# Proving $\int_0^{2\pi}e^{\lambda \cos(t)}\sin(nt)\ dt = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

As the title says, I'm trying to prove that

$$
\int_0^{2\pi}e^{\lambda \cos(t)}\sin(nt) = 0 \ \ (\forall n \in \mathbb{N}_0)
$$

Edit: the following calculation is wrong, as pointed out in the comments, since $\cos(t + \pi) = -\cos(t)$ and **not** $\cos(t)$.

So far I've done the following:

$$
\int_0^{2\pi}e^{\lambda \cos(t)}\sin(nt)\ dt =
\int_0^{\pi}e^{\lambda \cos(t)}\sin(nt)\ dt + 
\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}e^{\lambda \cos(t)}\sin(nt)\ dt = \\
\int_0^{\pi}e^{\lambda \cos(t)}\sin(nt)\ dt + \int_{0}^{\pi}e^{\lambda \cos(t + \pi)}\sin(nt + \pi n)\ dt = \\
\int_0^{\pi}e^{\lambda \cos(t)}\sin(nt)\ dt + \int_{0}^{\pi}e^{\lambda \cos(t)}\sin(nt)(-1)^n\ dt =\\
(1 + (-1)^n)\int_0^{\pi}e^{\lambda \cos(t)}\sin(nt)\ dt
$$

which proves the equation for odd $n$. Any ideas on how to prove this for $n$ even?

Comment: $\lambda\cos(t+\pi)\neq\lambda\cos(t)$

Comment: Oh well, I can't belive I missed that... thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sub $u=2 \pi -t$.

$$\int_0^{2\pi}e^{\lambda cos(t)}sin(nt)dt=-\int_{2 \pi}^{0} e^{\lambda cos(-u)}sin(-nu)du =-\int_0^{2 \pi} e^{\lambda cos(u)}sin(nu) du$$

Answer (score 3):

One can simply note that
$$ \int_0^{2\pi} e^{\lambda \cos{t}}\sin{nt} \, dt = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{\lambda \cos{t}}\sin{nt} \, dt, $$
since both functions have period dividing $2\pi$. But then this is the integral over a symmetric interval of the product of the even function $e^{\lambda \cos{t}}$ and the odd function $\sin{nt}$, which is zero.

Answer (score 3):

The integrand is odd and periodic. Exploit that fact.